# Как написать клиента для SOAP (web-service)

Tags: java, service, soap

Собственно говоря есть такая задача, есть ресурс ( он не секретный - http://ruzditest.eisnot.ru:8280/services/ruzdiUploadNotificationPackageService_v1_0?wsdl ). Необходимо написать к нему клиента. 
При попытки выполнить команду

`wsimport -d bin -s srchttp://ruzditest.eisnot.ru:8280/services/ruzdiUploadNotificationPackageService_v1_0?wsdl`

получаю такую ругань:

```
parsing WSDL...
[ERROR] Server returned HTTP response code: 503 for URL: http://ruzditest.eisnot.ru:8280/services/ruzdiUploadNotificationPackageService_v1_0?wsdl

Failed to read the WSDL document: http://ruzditest.eisnot.ru:8280/services/ruzdiUploadNotificationPackageService_v1_0?wsdl, because 1) could not find the document; /2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <wsdl:definitions>.

[ERROR] Could not find wsdl:service in the provided WSDL(s): 

At least one WSDL with at least one service definition needs to be provided.

Failed to parse the WSDL.
```

ok, с помощью curl скачиваю wsdl файл
и затем указываю уже напрямую wsdl получаю похожий эффект
parsing WSDL...

```
[ERROR] IOException thrown when processing "file:/C:/workspaceIvy/IvyNotariat/ruzdiUploadNotificationPackageService_v1_0?xsd=ruzdiUploadNotificationPackageService_v1_0.xsd". Exception: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\workspaceIvy\IvyNotariat\ruzdiUploadNotificationPackageService_v1_0?xsd=ruzdiUploadNotificationPackageService_v1_0.xsd (Синтаксическая ошибка в имени файла, имени папки или метке тома).


[WARNING] schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'ruzdiUploadNotificationPackageService_v1_0?xsd=ruzdiUploadNotificationPackageService_v1_0.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
line 4 of file:/C:/workspaceIvy/IvyNotariat/test.wsdl#types?schema1
```

Собственно вопрос, в чем затык?

Comment: вопрос `?` там у вас в имени файла каким образом появился? отсюда и `Синтаксическая ошибка в имени файла,`

Comment: @teran файл у меня просто test.wsdl называется

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по этой строке:

```
schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document
```

ваш WSDL зависит от XSD-схем, которых, либо нет на ресурсе, либо у вас, либо они повреждены.

Не используйте wsimport, попробуйте [maven jaxb codegen](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/maven-cxf-codegen-plugin-wsdl-to-java.html)

Comment: схемы запросить или найти валидные ссылки ;)

Comment: а вот это интересно, ресурс у меня есть. Я уже сам стал догадываться об этом но вы упорядочили хаос в моей голове :)